# openvpn client.up script erroring out

Tags: domain-name-system, openvpn

I'm using OpenVPN 2.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm having a little trouble getting "pull dhcp-options" working.  I have client.up and client.down under /etc/openvpn/, and I can see it running client.up, but it errors out with

Sun Jul  7 10:17:13 2013 us=188743 /etc/openvpn/client.up tun0 1500 1542 10.162.1.6    10.162.1.5 init
   resolvconf: Error: Command not recognized 
Usage: resolvconf (-d IFACE|-a IFACE|-u|--enable-updates|--disable-updates|--updates-are-enabled|--create-runtime-directories|--wipe-runtime-directories)

Has resolvconf changed so that the invocation being used in client.up is no longer valid?